# Where is the x-ray option in 2.8? (in Weight Paint mode)

Tags: transparency

I need to use the x-ray option for weight painting but I can only find the wireframe option using Z. Where can I find the x-ray?

Answer (score 1):

Update:

X-Ray doesn't work in *Weight Paint* mode. If you want to paint through, in the N panel > *Tool > Advanced*, deactivate the *Front Faces Only* option and under *Fallof* make sure that *Front-Face Falloff* is deactivated.

Also activate *Falloff Shape > Projected* (which will make the brush act like a cylinder and not a sphere). In 2.8 it was called *2D Falloff* in the *Options*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Whoops, somehow missed this comment. That's not quite what I'm looking for. In 2.79 there are two options to view your mesh. One is wireframe where you only see the vertices/edges/faces of your mesh from the angle you are looking. The other option is transparent, where you can view the vertices/edges/faces of the mesh you are facing in addition to those behind it. I'm looking for the transparency option in this case so that I can see what vertices I already have painted in weight paint mode from the front face instead of spinning it around to hit every vertice.

Comment: As moonboots said, it is alt-Z

Comment: I'm not sure why I was downvoted, actually X Ray doesn't seem to work in Weight Paint mode, and if the goal was to paint through, the option was called 2D Falloff as I said, now it is called Projected (with the Front Faces options disabled). I've edited my answer to make it more clear...